Why torque times theta is a scalar quantity work done

While reading a book, I encountered a statement asserting that work done in pure rotation is the product of torque and angular displacement. I understand that torque is a vector quantity. However, the book states that angular displacement is not a vector, and that we are not performing a scalar product. I am curious as to why the resulting work, despite involving a vector quantity, is ultimately a scalar quantity.

Displacement is a vector.

Angular displacement in general is not a vector quantity. Only differential angular displacements are vector quantities. In general you have to integrate $\vec{\tau }\cdot \vec{d{\theta}}$ over the interval you want to get the work done.

How is this homework?

Or, indeed, 'Check my work'.

Angular displacement is not a (pseudo)vector, but an infinitesimal angular displacement about a point O can be regarded as one, if we define it by:
$$d\vec{\theta}= \frac{\vec r \times d\vec s}{r^2}$$
in which $d\vec{\theta}$ is subtended at O by a displacement $d\vec s$ at a place with displacement $\vec r$ from O.
The torque, $\vec G$, about O of a force, $\vec F$, acting at $\vec r$ from O is
$$\vec G=\vec r \times \vec F$$
So
$$\vec G.d\vec \theta\ =\ \frac {(\vec r \times \vec F).(\vec r \times d\vec s)}{r^2}\ =\ (\mathbf{\hat r} \times \vec F).(\mathbf{\hat r} \times d\vec s)$$
Using the vector identity
$$(\vec a \times \vec b).(\vec c \times \vec d)=(\vec a.\vec c)(\vec b.\vec d)-(\vec a.\vec d)(\vec b.\vec c):$$
$$\vec G.d\vec \theta\ =\  ({\mathbf{\hat r}}.{\mathbf{\hat r}})(\vec F.d\vec s)-(\mathbf{\hat r}.d\vec s)(\mathbf{\hat r}.\vec F)\ =\ \vec F.d\vec s -F_r(ds)_r$$
that is
$$\vec F.d\vec s=\vec G.d\vec \theta+F_r (ds)_r.$$
The first term on the right might be called the tangential work, and the second term, the radial work.
